# Rational Zeros Theorem to show irrationality

Tags: number-theory

Show that $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is irrational using the rational zeros theorem, you have to find a polynomial that has $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ as a zero

Comment: Start with $x = \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$. Then $x^2 - 8 = \ldots$

Comment: So what is the problem: finding a polynomial, or using the rational zeroes theorem? What difficulties did you face when you tried the probelm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let x = √3 + √5 Then x² = 8+2√15 and (x²-8)²=60 from which you can find your polynomial. With the Rational Zero test it is easy to verify that there are no rational zeros